# Flex wrapping causes border to have padding

Tags: html, css, flexbox, word-wrap

I want to display 2 separate strings in-line when the screen is big enough. But when the width gets smaller, I want the 2nd string to move down. I'm currently using flex wrap, but it's adding extra padding to the right when the 2nd string does the wrap. Is there a way to get rid of this padding?

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/Dirst/1ep2tq9y/61/

```
<div class="entire">
  <div class="stringA">First string of text.</div>
  <div> Second string of text.</div>
</div>

.entire{
  border-style: solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: fit-content;
}

.stringA{
    color: green;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

[image: Inline when screen width is wide enough] [image: String 2 Wraps down when screen gets smaller]

I also tried adjusting the width of the containers (e.g., using max-width / min-width / fit-content), but it prevents the inline state from occurring.

I also tried using display inline / inline block, but they cause the borders to split up into two when the screen width becomes small:
https://jsfiddle.net/Dirst/hfexz7od/51/

```
<div class="entire">
  <div class="stringA">First string of text.</div>
  <div class="stringB">Second string of text.</div>
</div>

.entire{
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
  border-style: solid;
  display: inline;
}

.stringA{
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 5px;
  /*width: fit-content;*/
}
.stringB{
  display: inline-block;
  /*width: fit-content;*/
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

[image: Inline + Inline block wrapping]

I would like to only have the border wrap around both strings as one rectangle but without the right-padding caused by the wrap.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `span` instead of `div` for `display: inline-block;`

Here is the full of implementation

```css
.entire {
  border-style: solid;
  display: inline-block;
}

.stringA {
  color: green;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="entire">
  <span class="stringA">First string of text.</span>
  <span> Second string of text.</span>
</div>
```

You can try it out in this sanbox https://jsfiddle.net/tmj7eab6/

Comment: I would like to have the entire stringB to wrap down at once instead of one word at a time. I think another way to picture it is if we had two images. Is there a way to get rid of the padding when imageB wraps down? Or is this impossible with the way wrapping works? And the issue still seems to be there with the span method - there's a small padding (with the length of the word) that gets wrapped down.

Comment: Theoretically, it's not ideal for CSS, but we can try to achieve it with Javascript or media query (that also depends on your requirement and real designs). Could you share your real designs? I can help you to find some workarounds for it @Vikktour

Comment: It might not be doable since the two strings can change in length. Thanks for your feedback though Nick!

Comment: Sorry for my unuseful answer. Hopefully, you can find a way to fix it soon. :D  @Vikktour